# Can not start a script in monit

Tags: linux, monit

I have a script which have to run another script in background:

```
#!/bin/bash
( cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/hostcontrol-pipe/_data/ && ./run-pipe.sh ) &
```

Firstly it changes directory and runs a script. run-pipe.sh creates named pipes in its directory.
And I have a monit config file to monitor this script and to restart it if it's not running:

```
check program check-pipe with path /bin/bash -c "echo 'ping' > /var/lib/docker/volumes/hostcontrol-pipe/_data/host-pipe" with timeout 1 seconds
    if status != 0 then
        restart
    start program = "/var/lib/docker/volumes/hostcontrol-pipe/_data/monit.sh"
```

First line checks the script is running writing to its pipe, it works.
The line "start program" doesn't work - the script doesn't run and it's abscent in the "ps ax". But I see in "sudo monit -vI":

```
'check-pipe' start: '/var/lib/docker/volumes/hostcontrol-pipe/_data/monit.sh'
'check-pipe' started
'check-pipe' program started
```

So, why monit cant run the script? I tried different variants, but cant run it. I can run it without changing directory (cd), but this is nessecary.

Answer (score 0):

Actually monit could not run a script in background because where wasn't output. After adding output file it started to work.

```
start program = "/bin/bash -c 'cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/hostcontrol-pipe/_data && ./run-pipe.sh > 1.log &'"
```

Or otherwise /dev/null as output stream.